# Get current page request url in handlebars?

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there a way to the current request url or path in Handlebars? I need to be able to switch what parts of the theme is loaded based on paths. I've tried {{url}} ... no luck. Using latest Stencil with Cornerstone.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do something like this for a project with 3 different category page layouts. Without custom category templates in Stencil, you have to get a little creative.

First, inject the handlebars URL into your category.js file using the BigCommerce's inject handlebar helper seen [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/customizing-javascript#HBintoJS). Then parse it so you get only the unique parts, then perform some logic based on what you want to do.

I used the breadcrumb li length as an indicator of how deep I was in the category tree. There is likely a better way, but this is what I thought of first, and it worked just fine.

category.html

```
{{inject "currentPage" category.url}}
```

category.js

```
    var pageURL = this.context.currentPage;
    var pageURL = pageURL.replace(/\//g," ").replace("http:","").replace("storeurl.mybigcommerce.com","").replace("storeurl.com","").trim();
    var catName = pageURL.substr(0,pageURL.indexOf(' '));

    console.log('pageURL = ' + pageURL);
    console.log('catName = ' + catName);
    console.log($('ul.breadcrumbs li').length);

    if( $('ul.breadcrumbs li').length == 3 ){
            if(catName == "black-decker"){
                if($(".cat-img").length){
                    $(".page").addClass("model-list");
                    $(".cat-img").hide();
                    $(".page").append("<div class='model-wrap'><div class='model-catalog' data-reveal-id='myModal'><a href='#'><img class='i-img' src='https://store-p3ubwr6cgq.mybigcommerce.com/product_images/uploaded_images/i-img.jpg'><span>Where is my model number?</span><img class='popup-click' src=" + catImg + "></a><span class='click-larger'>Click to view larger</span></div></div>");
                    $(".sidebarBlock-heading").text("Select Your Model Number Below:");
                    $(".brand-img").each(function(){
                        $(this).addClass(catName);
                    });
                } else {
                    $(".page").addClass("model-list");
                    $(".sidebarBlock-heading").text("Select Your Model Number Below:");
                    $(".brand-img").each(function(){
                        $(this).addClass(catName);
                    });
                    // make page full width
                    $(".page-sidebar.cf.Left").addClass("full-width");
                }
            }
     // MORE CODE etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, not much doc on this stuff!